# AsyncTask in android app for more than one REST endpoint

Tags: java, android, rest, android-asynctask

In Android is there a better way than using a single `AsyncTask` with a parameter to work out which REST endpoint to call?

e.g. I need to call:

```
 www.test.com/api/room/id    
 www.test.com/api/room/id/booking
```

**`AsyncTask`** is designed for a single **`doInBackground()`** method that does a single thing, e.g. call:

```
www.test.com/api/room/id
```

I don't want to create multiple **`AsyncTasks`** instances, one for each REST endpoint.

The back end would use:

```
RoomClient = new RoomClient();
roomClient.getID()
roomClient.getBookingForRoom()
```

In Android it looks like I'd need

```
class RoomFromId extends AsyncTask
...
call www.test.com/api/room/id

class BookingForRoom extends AsyncTask
..
call www.test.com/api/room/id/booking
```

What I'd ideally like in the Android app is the idiom of writing a rest client that can call all REST endpoints in the background, without having to do each one in its own **`AsyncTask`**. I'd prefer to use what Android has, rather than a 3rd party library.

Comment: You can make as many requests as you want in `doInBackground` and encapsulate the results in a class

Comment: I only want to make one request in doInBackground. The request can be to one of multiple REST endpoints. So the Q is how to send that choice to a single AsyncTask

Comment: You can use the constructor in your class extending AsyncTask

Comment: That's an interesting idea for the constructor, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a generic Class extends from AsyncTask that return response in a generic type that extends from YourBaseModel (I called it M)

```
public class HttpRequest<M extends BaseModel> extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, M> {
public enum RequestMethod {
    GET("GET"), POST("POST");

    private final String requestMethod;

    RequestMethod(String requestMethod) {
        this.requestMethod = requestMethod;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return requestMethod;
    }
}

    private Context context = null;
    private String url;
    private OnResponseCallback onResponseCallback;
    private OnFailureCallback onFailureCallback;
    private RequestMethod method;
    private int statusCode;
    private String message;
    private Class<M> responseModel;
    private Object body = null;
    private String token;

    private HttpRequest() {

    }

    @Override
    protected M doInBackground(Object... voids) {
        try {
             HttpURLConnection connection = getHttpConnection();
             connection.connect();

            int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() / 100 != 2) {
                this.statusCode = statusCode;
                this.message = connection.getResponseMessage();
                return JsonParser.getErrorBodyAs(responseModel, statusCode, 
message);
            }

            InputStreamReader streamReader = new
                    InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

            return JsonParser.getErrorBodyAs(responseModel, statusCode, 
convertInputStreamToString(streamReader));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private HttpURLConnection getHttpConnection() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(this.url);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) 
 url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(method.getValue());
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);

    if (method == RequestMethod.POST) {
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        if (body != null) {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(new Gson().toJson(body));
            writer.flush();
        }
    }

    return connection;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(M m) {
    if (m == null) {
        if ((message != null && !message.equals("") && statusCode != 0)) {
            HttpException httpException = new HttpException(statusCode, message);
            onFailureCallback.onFailure(httpException);
        } else {
            onFailureCallback.onFailure("unknown error");
        }
    } else {
        onResponseCallback.onResponse(m);
    }
}

public static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStreamReader inputStreamReader) throws IOException {
    if (inputStreamReader == null) {
        return "";
    }

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    String inputLine;
    String result;

    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
    }

    reader.close();
    inputStreamReader.close();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

static public class Builder {
    HttpRequest t = new HttpRequest();

    public Builder setContext(Context context) {
        t.context = context;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setUrl(String url) {
        t.url = url;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setRequestMethod(RequestMethod method) {
        t.method = method;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setBody(Object body) {
        t.body = body;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setToken(String token) {
        t.token = token;
        return this;
    }

    public HttpRequest get() {
        return t;
    }

    public HttpRequest run(Class<?> responseTypeClass,
                           OnResponseCallback onResponseCallback,
                           OnFailureCallback onFailureCallback) {
        t.responseModel = responseTypeClass;
        t.onResponseCallback = onResponseCallback;
        t.onFailureCallback = onFailureCallback;
        t.execute();
        return t;
    }

    public Builder() {
    }
 }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
HttpRequest.Builder builder = new HttpRequest.Builder();
builder.setContext(context)
            .setRequestMethod(HttpRequest.RequestMethod.POST)
            .setBody(body)
            .setUrl("http://url")
            .run(YourResponeModel.class, new OnResponseCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Object response) {
                },
               new OnFailureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Object throwable) {

                    }
            });
```

Comment: That looks really good, thanks. So instead of a single run() method I could have builder.getID() and builder.getBookingForRoom() which set up the internals with the correct url and parameters and called execute. i.e. moving a lot of the initialisation into the builder, which would hide the urls from the caller. i.e. I want the app to work at the domain layer (Room, Booking etc) and not to care how the builder gets those domain objects (body, url etc). This looks like a great way to do it.

Comment: Yes, you can. But the better way is creating a class like RoomRepo and call All Room APIs there, just set the URL to  www.test.com/api/room/id  or  www.test.com/api/room/booking. don't complex the builder

Comment: I see. So Builder works with the raw data, i.e. send Body to url and get response data back. It would be the job of RoomRepo to give Builder the correct Body and url and make sense of the response (a Room object). If I have a Beacon and I need to get a Room id from it, roomRepo.getRoomIdFromBeaconID(String beaconID) would set up the Builder with the correct Body, url, callbacks etc and turn the response JSON from the builder into a Room object.

Answer (score 1):

In the class you create that extends AsyncTask you can create a constructor and pass whatever you want/need.

In this case you can define a class ApiManager that extends AsyncTask and pass a constant that defines the method to call. 
In that constructor you can save the variable to your ApiManager object and then check it in the doInBackground method.

So, to call the room/id you could do something like:

```
new ApiManager(ROOM_FROM_ID).execute(...
```

And to call the room/id/booking:

```
new ApiManager(BOOKING_FOR_ROOM).execute(...
```

And the ApiManager class should be something like:

```
class ApiManager extends AsyncTask... {
    private int method;
    public ApiManager(int method) {
        this.method = method;
    }
    ...
}
```